# Trying to Transfer Large Mac OS to System with Less Storage

Tags: mac, storage, data-transfer

Trying to transfer data from a 400GB Macbook pro to a smaller sized drive (250GB). System and Private directories are taking up a huge amount of space. Can I safely transfer most things and exclude the private directory ? What directories are critical for functionality? I apologize I am rathe new to the Mac file system. Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Hit restart, when it starts up again, hold shift. You'll get into safe mode. After a minute of doing nothing, restart again. Don't hold anything this time & boot normally. See if the size of private clears up. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: I've done this a few times. I have also tried clearing the files (without deleting the folders) in /private to no avail.

Comment: Use something like Disk inventory X to find out the distribution of storage

Comment: And depending on what is going on here a utility like Onyx https://titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html that deletes caches, temp files and does all the system maintenance chores built-in to macOS might help as well, and it is freeware.

Comment: I would recommend backing your system up with Time Machine to an external HDD. In Time Machine Preferences, add /System and all these mystery directories as excluded folders. Then, make a new install of macOS to the target disk, and when you're setting it up, it should ask if you want to transfer data from an old Mac. Plug in the external backup disk and select "From a Time Machine Backup." macOS will move your applications, files and preferences back into place, but it will use the new installation for the rest of the things you excluded. That way, you won't end up with an unstable system.